# Multiplying a vector by a scalar

Tags: vectors

can someone help me answer this question? The question goes like this:

```
Given V is a vector of magnitude 2 state

(a) a  vector  of  magnitude  4  in  the direction of V
```

Comment: What is the magnitude of $\pm2V$?

Answer (score 1):

If the magnitude of $V$ is $2$ then the magnitude of $2V$ is $4$ and they have the same direction as well.

Comment: You have solved an issue that can be qualified of "small magnitude" :)